# Indentation/protrusion of first line in redefined quote with microtype

Tags: microtype, quoting, protrusion

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\renewenvironment{quote}
{\list{}{\leftmargin0.5cm \rightmargin0cm}
\item\relax\fontsize{9.8pt}{11.4pt}\selectfont}
{\endlist}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
    When \\
When
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

This leads to unjustified lines/letters:

[image]

The problem does not appear if I add `\par` and move the `\fontsize` command, but this also slightly affects vertical spaces:

```
\renewenvironment{quote}{\par
\fontsize{9.8pt}{11.4pt}\selectfont
\list{}{\leftmargin0.5cm\rightmargin0cm}
\item\relax}
{\endlist}
```

My question is related to much older ones, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13666/microtype-and-quote-environment-leads-to-different-indent-of-first-line/13711) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93992/protrusion-issue-pdftex-bug-microtype-bug-or-latex-bug) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17536/microtype-protrusion-incompatible-quote-changemargin-and-adjustwidth-environmen), and apparently there have been fixes introduced (I use TeX Live 2021) but I'm still not able to figure out a solution. How is the correct way to change the quote environment as I intend to?

Comment: this is fixed in microtype v3.0e, which won't be confused by the font selection commands anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the space (after the `}` at the start of the environment) it is not being ignored as you have mis-placed the font change, also for microtype, I think you need `\leftprotrusion` so that the start of the text is adjusted like the text afer a line break.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\renewenvironment{quote}
{\list{}{\leftmargin0.5cm \rightmargin0cm}%
\item\relax\fontsize{9.8pt}{11.4pt}\selectfont\leftprotrusion\ignorespaces}
{\endlist}


\begin{document}

AAAA BBB CCC
AAAA BBB CCC
AAAA BBB CCC
AAAA BBB CCC
AAAA BBB CCC
AAAA BBB CCC
AAAA BBB CCC
AAAA BBB CCC
AAAA BBB CCC
AAAA BBB CCC
\begin{quote}
    When \\
When
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

or simpler as noted in comments

```
\fontsize{9.8pt}{11.4pt}\selectfont\item\relax}
```

so that `microtype` can handle the protusion of the characer after `\item`wihout being confused by the font change in between.

Comment: When I redefine quote as you suggest, the [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638902/uneven-line-spacing-in-paragraph) you helped me solve yesterday reappears and the preceding paragraph is squeezed. Is there still a way to redefine it without `\par`?

Comment: @johnny7 sorry yes, fixed that,  actually if you put microtype back you get a slight shift in the secod line, but not the first but I think that's a different issue

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `\ignorespaces` to the definition remains without effect for me.

Comment: run the code as posted here and  you should get the output shown,.

Comment: When I reenable microtype, the first line is still indented as in my original code.

Comment: no less, the original code it had a space, but as I say microtype adjusts the W after `\\ ` but not at the start.... ah seems to be a microtype feature, try now, I added `\leftprotrusian`

Comment: Yes, the `\leftprotrusian` does the trick! `\ignorespaces` is not needed to fix the wrong indent of the first line. Thanks again!

Comment: Page 25 of the microtype documentation mentions a built-in patch for `item` that addresses the exact problem described here. The fontsize change seems to override this patch.

Comment: @johnny7 ah try putting the font change just before `\item` then ending with `\item\relax`

Comment: Yes, that makes the `\leftprotrusion` obsolete! And I thought I had tried every position of the font change... I also saw other [examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45725/redefining-quote-environment-with-tiny-font-and-double-quote-signs) that gave a font change after `\relax`.

Comment: @johnny7 I added a note to the answer, thanls